# How do I edit the .env.template on my MacBook Air?

Tags: editor, autogpt

I'm trying to edit the file named “.env.template” inside the Auto-GPT folder. I don't even know if I have a code editor installed and I'm running the latest version of MacOS. Trying to install AutoGPT and stuck on this step:

[image]

Have the terminal window open, but unsure where to find the editor to change the .env

Answer (score 0):

Just copy that .env.template and rename it .env

Remember to un-comment any attributes that are useful for you, paste your Open AI API Key down that file